# Deshabilitar campos de un select en html

Tags: html, formularios, select

estoy haciendo un select en un html y trato de hacer que cuando se escoja la opcion % en % respecto dia anterior automaticamente se inhabilite el cambo "Horas", alguna idea de que pueda hacer?

```html
<tr>
  <td color="#66ccff"><strong>Patrón 1 (<select name="TipoPatron1" id="TipoPatron1">
        <option value="00" selected="selected">T desde el encendido</option>
        <option value="01">T desde las 12:00</option>
        <option value="10">T en % respecto día anterior</option>
      </select>
      )</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <table border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr color="#ccff00" align="center">
          <td>Cambio</td>
          <td>Hora/%</td>
          <td>Minutos</td>
          <td>Dimado</td>
          <td>Dimado Entrada</td>
          <td>Color</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Error mio, ya lo he puesto bien

Comment: Necesitas agregar datos de ejemplo para poder visualizar el problema. Por eso te deje lo del [mre]